# Bootstrap 3 push pull is not working on xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot understand why my push pull is not working. The order on `>= col-sm` is correct. When I am going to `col-xs`, I would like the order is changed like below:

> sm : | A | B | C |
>
> < xs : | C | A | B |

Before I add `push-pull` [demopage](http://vouzalis.dk/push-pull.html).

After I add `push-pull` [demopage](http://vouzalis.dk/push-pull-after.html).

The only difference between the 2 demosites is that i added: `push / pull`
on the `col` tags.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

```css
#content{
    background:#ffffff;
  }

  .hr-spacing {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Contact page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-push-3">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3><i class="icon-pushpin main-color"></i>A</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <address>
                            <strong>Company name</strong><br/>
                            Stackroad 1<br/>
                            1234 London<br/>
                            <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i><a href="tel:+4512345678"> + 45 12345678</a><br/>
                            <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i><a href="mailto:info@companyname.com"> info@companyname.com</a>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel hidden-xs">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2>A.A</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      <a href="da-dk/#">Link 1</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                      <a href="#">Link 2</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                      <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 3</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                      <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 4</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                      <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 6</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                      <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 6</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-push-9">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2>B</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, imperdiet leo id quis est, blandit velit eget natoque pulvinar porttitor aliquam, vehicula vitae. Ipsum a amet diam. Aliquam elit lorem justo, libero gravida, nunc wisi facilisis vestibulum enim vitae pretium, suspendisse fringilla et interdum convallis ut vestibulum. Rhoncus massa lectus suspendisse ultrices, parturient ac eget ligula scelerisque lacus tortor,</p>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-pull-4">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3><i class="icon-time main-color"></i>C</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th>Call us</th>
                                    <th>Write us</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="tel:+4512345678">+ 45 12 34 56 78</td>
                                    <td><a href="mailto:info@company.dk">info@company.dk</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th>Dag</th>
                                    <th>Tidspunkt</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="success">
                                    <td>Mandag</td>
                                    <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="success">
                                    <td>Tirsdag</td>
                                    <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="success">
                                    <td>Onsdag</td>
                                    <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="success">
                                    <td>Torsdag</td>
                                    <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="warning">
                                    <td>Fredag</td>
                                    <td>8:00 - 15:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="danger"> 
                                    <td>Lørdag</td>
                                    <td>Lukket</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="danger">
                                    <td>Søndag</td>
                                    <td>Lukket</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th>Driftstatus</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="dot"></span> Normal drift</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try my code.Let me know if there is any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
    #content{
        background:#ffffff;
      }
    
      .hr-spacing {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    
      .dot {
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: green;
      }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Contact page</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3><i class="icon-time main-color"></i>C</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th>Call us</th>
                                        <th>Write us</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="tel:+4512345678">+ 45 12 34 56 78</td>
                                        <td><a href="mailto:info@company.dk">info@company.dk</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th>Dag</th>
                                        <th>Tidspunkt</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <td>Mandag</td>
                                        <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <td>Tirsdag</td>
                                        <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <td>Onsdag</td>
                                        <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <td>Torsdag</td>
                                        <td>8:00 - 16:00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>Fredag</td>
                                        <td>8:00 - 15:00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="danger"> 
                                        <td>Lørdag</td>
                                        <td>Lukket</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="danger">
                                        <td>Søndag</td>
                                        <td>Lukket</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th>Driftstatus</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span class="dot"></span> Normal drift</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-4">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3><i class="icon-pushpin main-color"></i>A</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <address>
                                <strong>Company name</strong><br/>
                                Stackroad 1<br/>
                                1234 London<br/>
                                <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i><a href="tel:+4512345678"> + 45 12345678</a><br/>
                                <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i><a href="mailto:info@companyname.com"> info@companyname.com</a>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel hidden-xs">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2>A.A</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <a href="da-dk/#">Link 1</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                          <a href="#">Link 2</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                          <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 3</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                          <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 4</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                          <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 6</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                          <a href="/da-dk/page/#">Link 6</a><hr class="hr-spacing"/>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-4">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2>B</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
    
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, imperdiet leo id quis est, blandit velit eget natoque pulvinar porttitor aliquam, vehicula vitae. Ipsum a amet diam. Aliquam elit lorem justo, libero gravida, nunc wisi facilisis vestibulum enim vitae pretium, suspendisse fringilla et interdum convallis ut vestibulum. Rhoncus massa lectus suspendisse ultrices, parturient ac eget ligula scelerisque lacus tortor,</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/hyeczrvt/12/

I have adjusted layout and bootstrap classes.

Bootstrap is a mobile first CSS framework, so you need to format layout according mobile flow ( eg: C|A|B ). Then rearrange div's according to desktop flow using bootstrap `push` and `pull` classes.

Try my code. It works for you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you a lot. Working perfect :) I am just going through the code to understand it also.